# Поиск в базе через Spring Data Jpa

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Есть два @Entity - Meal и Restaurant, взаимосвязанные через @OneToMany - ресторан имеет `List<Meal> mealList`. Вот сущности (геттеры и сеттеры намеренно не указал, но в коде они есть):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "restaurants")
public class Restaurant {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Please fill the name")
    private String name;

    @NotBlank(message = "Please fill the address")
    private String address;

    private LocalDateTime registered;

    private boolean isEnabled = true;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "restaurant")
    private List<Meal> meals;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "restaurant")
    private List<Vote> voteList;

    public Restaurant() {
    }

    public Restaurant(String name, String address, List<Meal> meals) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.meals = meals;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "meals")
public class Meal {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String description;

    private Integer price;

    private LocalDate date;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id", nullable = false)
    private Restaurant restaurant;

    public Meal() {
    }

    public Meal(String description, Integer price, Restaurant restaurant) {
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
        this.restaurant = restaurant;
    }
}
```

В базе данных таблицы выглядят следующим образом:

```
CREATE TABLE restaurants
(
    id         INTEGER   DEFAULT nextval('hibernate_sequence') PRIMARY KEY,
    address    VARCHAR(255)            NOT NULL,
    name       VARCHAR(255)            NOT NULL,
    registered TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
    is_enabled BOOLEAN   DEFAULT TRUE  NOT NULL,
    votes      INTEGER   DEFAULT 0     NOT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX restaurants_unique_name_address_idx ON restaurants (name, address);

CREATE TABLE meals
(
    id            INTEGER DEFAULT nextval('hibernate_sequence') PRIMARY KEY,
    date          DATE    DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
    description   VARCHAR(255)          NOT NULL,
    price         INTEGER               NOT NULL,
    restaurant_id INTEGER               NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (restaurant_id) REFERENCES restaurants (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX meals_unique_restId_date_description_idx ON meals (restaurant_id, date, description);
```

Вопрос - как из @Repository, реализующий интерфейс `Crud<Restaurant, Integer>`, вытащить рестораны, где у блюд указана конкретная дата (например, сегодняшняя)?
Возможно ли это реализовать через Data Jpa методы, именуемые findBy()?

Comment: `List<Restaurant> findAllByMealList_Date(Date date)` - попробуйте

Comment: Было бы лучше добавить сами сущности (Entities), чтобы понятнее было. Как создавались таблицы - это не так важно

Comment: Добавил классы сущностей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы использовал бы тут `@Query` (JPQL).

В теории должно выглядить что-то в этом роде:

```java
public interface RestaurantRepository extends CrudRepository<Restaurant, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT restaur from Restaurnats as restaur join fetch restaur.meals as meal where meal.date = ?1")
    List<Restaurant> findAllByMealsByDate(LocalDate date)
}
```

Comment: Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: restaurnats is not mapped [SELECT restaur from restaurnats as restaur join fetch restaur.meals as meal where meal.date = ?1]

Comment: я немного модифицировал ваш код, и он заработал! спасибо большое!

Comment: @MaksimRybalkin в связи с тем, что я не видел сущности, пришлось писать на абу)

Answer (score 1):

```
@Query("select distinct r from Restaurant r join fetch r.meals m where m.date=?1")
List<Restaurant> findByRestaurantMealDate(LocalDate date);
```

Вот так работает! Всем спасибо!